# Tell Linux to use latest libusbx I have downloaded

Tags: usb, raspbian

Background, I'm trying to play with a Kinect camera and Python.

When I tried to make freenect (manual install) on Ubuntu 12.04, it complained about undefined libusb_get_parent.

However, it works fine on Ubuntu 14.04.

Next I go to a Raspberry PI, and try to get that manual install to work there. No dice. Same libusb_get_parent complaint.

So I apt-get update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, no dice. I try to get libusb-dev and all sorts of things.

So I do `dpkg -s libusb-1.0-0-dev` on Ubuntu 12.02. It says it uses

```
Source: libusb-1.0 
Version: 2:1.0.9~rc3-2ubuntu1
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 it says:

```
Source: libusbx
Version: 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2
```

And finally on the Raspberry PI:

```
Source: libusbx
Version: 2:1.0.11-1
```

So I figure, if I can get a newer version of libusbx onto the Raspberry PI, I should at least get a little farther.

I downloaded the latest libusbx here (http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbx/files/releases/1.0.18/source/)

And then did:

```
$ sudo su
$ ./configure && make && make install && sudo ldconfig
```

From the directory that I extracted. (It appeared to configure and make.)

I again did dpkg -s libusb-1.0-0-dev thinking I'd now have my new 1.0.18 version, but that's not the case. It's still 1.0.11.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're talking about [this](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the manual install (for Ubuntu) except I'm doing it on Raspbian. The problem seems to be an older usblib(x)

Comment: I can see some main contributors in their openkinect chatroom on [freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/), they could maybe help if you can't figure out how to use the library version you want...

Comment: Thanks. I've gotten the kinect to work on Ubuntu. I'm actually less interested in the kinect aspect as I am learning how Linux links these different libraries during make, and what it takes to drop in my own (such as libusbx 1.0.18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've compiled from source.  This means that Ubuntu's package management system doesn't know about it.  Package managers only know about packages that were installed using package managers (such as `apt` and `dpkg`).  Additionally, when a package manager installs an newer version, it uninstalls older versions.  As the package manager didn't install this new version, it follows that it won't have installed your original. Hence why `dpkg` still shows the older version.

If I were in your shoes, I'd run `make uninstall` on the source to remove the files.  Then I'd download the `libusbx` package for Ubuntu 14.04 and try to install that manually.  If it doesn't complain about missing dependencies then you should hopefully get away with not compiling.

Versions should be backward compatible, so hopefully installing a later version won't break any installed packages that already depend on the current `libusbx`.

If the above doesn't work for you, consider building the package from source.  This process creates a `deb` package for you, which you can then install with your normal package managers.  Done this way, you're `dpkg` command will show the newest version and the older version will be removed.

There is a good Stack Exchange question that covers this process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source).

Comment: Ok, I've compiled from source so the package manager doesn't know about it. That makes sense. So when I run the setup program (the manual install from the openkinect page from the comment), it tells me this: 

"Linking C executable ../bin/freenect-chunkview
../lib/libfreenect.so.0.5.0: undefined reference to `libusb_get_parent'" 

So clearly it's trying to link to the old default usblib. How do I tell it to use the new one I downloaded? Does the linker rely on the packagemanager too?

Comment: The linker doesn't rely on the package manager.  If you choose to bypass the package manager then you're on your own the whole way.  You'll need to make sure the `configure` options are correct for your distro and once you've compiled and installed you need to update the linker (`ldconfig`) so that the system is aware of the file. When you configure, it might be worth settings things up so that they are installed in `/usr/local/lib` instead of the usual `/usr/lib` in order to keep things apart.

Comment: Ok, so my issue is on the `make` side of the `libfreenect`. I need to tell it to look in `~/libusbx/libusbx-1.0.18/`? I tried this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/libusbx/libusbx-1.0.18` and `make` on freenect still complains no libusb_get_part. I see the libusb_get_parent in the .h file of the libusbx I downloaded. It's not in the default one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whoops, nevermind, I think I wasn't deleting my build directory and starting once the new usblibx was installed.  I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  However, I think that instead you should answer your own question (which is fine) with what you did to fix it.  You've compiled manually, while I was suggesting you create a new `deb` file - two different methods. You could document the process you carried out in an answer which may help someone who stumbles on this question the future. Glad you got it to work.

Comment: True enough, but you answered my original question well, why does dpkg not show the new package? Because dpkg wasn't used in installing it.